# JFrame Displayed Text Won't update

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea, jtextpane

I'm working on a monopoly program that displays all the game info, such as name, bank account, and properties owned, in a separate JFrame. I have no problem starting either and displaying the correct info but neither updates upon request. So far I've tried JPanes and JTextAreas all following similar code.

```
JFrame infoFrame = new JFrame();
String finString;
JTextPane info = new JTextPane();

info.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
info.setEditable(true);
infoFrame.add(info);
infoFrameControl();
info.setEditable(false);

void infoFrameControl(){
    finString = "Current Standings\n=================\n";

    for(int i=0; i<players.size(); i++){

        //this loop determines what is stored in finString
        //I know this works because I've printed it in the console
    }

    finString += "\n";
    System.out.println(finString);

    info.setText(finString);    
}
```

This works fine until I call this method from another class using this code

```
mn.info.setEditable(true);
mn.infoFrameControl();
mn.info.setEditable(false);
```

where mn is an object of the class that holds the infoFrameControl() class. At this point, it has never updated. I've also used info.updateUI() but that hasn't worked either. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Comment: The likely cause might be, the instance you are trying to update isn't the one that is actually displayed on the screen

Comment: how can I make sure that the right instance is being displayed?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see how there can be any way to tell based on what you've posted so far, hence the reason for my request above -- that you post a simplified yet compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your error for us, a [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org). The only suggestion I can give you is to go through your code and search for wherever you call the `InfoFrameControl`'s constructor. Any where you do this, you create a new instance.

Comment: Pull the game information into a GUI model, and pass an instance of the GUI model to your JFrames.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, `InfoFrameControl` is a method not a class, the code of which is provided. And i'm not sure how to provide an sscce because there is too much code that i'm not sure what will and won't be of help. what I have provided you is everything that I have found that interacts with `infoFrameControl` and the info object. infoFrameControl determines what text to place in the JTextArea/JPane/JLabel. the first three lines are global, the next four are in a method called initiallize. `infoFramControl` is a method of its own, and the last three lines are in a different class

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't know how to do that. I'm not well versed in Java GUIs

Comment: Take a look at my [Dice Game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=460) article and see if that helps explain what a GUI model is.

Comment: I wish I could "up-vote" your link, @GilbertLeBlanc, as that's a nice little article. To the OP (original poster), sorry, I was mistaken on the name of the class, but my suggestion remains the same -- a rough way to see how many times an instance is created, look at how many times its constructor is called. The constructor for the display class should only be called **once**, and so you may wish to check that this is in fact so.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, I looked at your code and have come to the conclusion that I am in way over my head. I decided to use a blank, premade button (that I didn't show) and have that call to display a series of JOptionPanes showing the players stats. Thanks for all the help from everyone but I'm not confident enough in `Swing` to do this. and thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels for your patience but your comment confused me as well as @GilbertLeBlanc's code so I know I have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks truly for the help though.

Comment: Maybe start from the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) then.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too well-versed with `Swing`, but perhaps, instead of a `JTextPane` you should be using a `JLabel` inside of your `JFrame`? You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html), but it appears to be as easy to switch text as you have shown above.

Comment: I believe I've tried JLabels as well. I just forgot to say that. I've had no luck with those either